# Django Storages AWS_QUERYSTRING_AUTH Not Working

Tags: python, django, amazon-s3, boto

I have been trying to solve this and so far unable to do so on my own. There are several different post in regards to the reverse of my issue as to not wanting authentication in the S3 url.

I am using Django-Storages with the following in my `settings.py`:

```
AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME = 'testbucket'

AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = 'xxxxx'

AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = 'xxxxxx'

AWS_QUERYSTRING_AUTH = True

AWS_QUERYSTRING_EXPIRE = 3600'

from datetime import datetime, timedelta

AWS_HEADERS = {
    'Expires': (datetime.now() + timedelta(days=365*10)).strftime('%a, %d %b %Y 00:00:00 GMT')
}

AWS_S3_SECURE_URLS = True

AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN = '%s.s3.amazonaws.com' % AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME

MEDIA_URL = "https://%s/" % AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN

DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.s3boto.S3BotoStorage'
```

No issues saving or listing files but none of the urls have the authentication query string.

An [example of the url](https://testbucket.s3.amazonaws.com/docfolder/20151004/testimage.jpg) being returned.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: I'm having the same problem. One thing I noticed was that `AWS_DEFAULT_ACL = 'private'` needs to be set to even make the querystring necessary.

Answer (score 4):

The answer is that django-storages querystrings are not compatible with custom domains.

Comment: is this really true?

Comment: Yes, or at least it was true at the time

Comment: The following issue can be found here: https://github.com/jschneier/django-storages/issues/165

Answer (score 0):

Do you notice that a quote is missing here?
AWS_QUERYSTRING_EXPIRE = 3600'

It should be:
AWS_QUERYSTRING_EXPIRE = '3600'